Is it possible to trade in your phone at the Apple Store even if the website says you must use the return kit?
I've purchased the iPhone 16 Pro today, with a pickup scheduled for next week. When I got the 14 Pro on launch day two years ago, I was able to trade it in right there at the store. But this time it didn't seem possible, with the order email stating:

Please note that you will not be able to trade in your device in person at the Apple Store.

According to some Reddit comments, apparently they don't do in-store trade-ins close to launch, which contradicts my 2022 experience where I was able to do a trade-in on the very first day the 14 Pro came out.
But what's the actual policy? Can I still expect to be able to do the trade-in despite what the email says, assuming the store is not too busy at the time?

NB: I'll answer the question myself next week based on personal experience. But some links to official Apple answers on the subject or news articles would be better for a canonical answer.


It looks like you already have your answer, directly from Apple.  I think you'd have to cancel the order, which you might not be able to do if it's already processed, and place a new order for store pickup.

@fsb see my answer below, as I’ve suspected the email was wrong. Got my refund immediately on-site :-)

The answer is: yes, it’s possible as of October 2024 and you can safely ignore the email. The Apple Store employees confirmed its standard procedure for customers to change their trade-in method.
Below is my (redacted) receipt from the store for reference. I was able to get the refund sent immediately to my credit card.

